# Meteor.publish on multiple collections

Tags: meteor

I'm having trouble wrapping my head how I can perform the following scenario.

I want to build an interface that shows a user's current inbox.

I need to get some information from the following collections.

```
Conversation
Users
Messages
```

The interface would look like this.

---

```
Chat with {{ user }}
{{ lastMessageSent }}
```

---

I don't want to publish all the threads for a user, and all the messages (since there may be a lot). How can I write a query that publishes just the last message for a Conversation? How can I also write a query that just gets the Users involved in the Conversation.

I don't know the right messages to query for, until the Conversations thread comes back since the message IDs are in the thread itself.

Comment: Just to expand. Looks like this is a common problem with several potential solutions, none of which are that clean. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/

Comment: Do you really have to make joins or can you subscribe to the collections separately?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?